# What are the parameters for a web service in vba

Tags: c#, wcf, vba, parameters, endpoint

I wanted  to know what are the different parameters to call a WCFService with VBA ? I've  found this :

```
Dim addr As String
addr = "service:mexAddress=""net.http://y000zvk:7878/_vti_bin/Services/RetrieveList.svc/mex"","
addr = addr + "address=""net.http://y000zvk:7878/_vti_bin/Services/RetrieveList.svc/mex"","
addr = addr + "contract=""ServiceReference1.RetrieveList"", contractNamespace=""http://test.com"","
addr = addr + "binding=""basicHttpBinding"",bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""

Dim service1 As Object
Set service1 = GetObject(addr)

MsgBox service1.GetSiteTitle()
```

But I don't really know what to pu in the contract, binding, binding Namespace parameters. 
I've created my WCF Services with C# and this is my app.config endpoint :

```
<client>
        <endpoint address="http://y000zvk:7878/_vti_bin/Services/RetrieveList.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_RetrieveList"
            contract="ServiceReference1.RetrieveList" name="BasicHttpBinding_RetrieveList" />
</client>
```

Do you have any ideas how i can call my web service ? For information when i'm in debug mode i get this error :

The MetadataExchangeClient instance could not be initialized because no Binding is available for scheme 'net.http'. You can supply a Binding in the constructor, or specify a configurationName.
Parameter name: scheme

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of net.http -> use http

I'm assuming you've edited a net.tcp:// address and replaced only half the scheme?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help,
Yes it was that :).

Anyway i'm using another solution for my problem, but thanks ;)